# Guardar datos en laravel-vue

Tags: laravel, json, vue.js

Tengo un pequeño problema bien básico a mi parecer, lo que sucede es que estoy tratando de guardar unos datos, pero no puedo, esto lo intento hacer con vue.
en data de una instancia de Vue tengo esto

```
newWarranty : {'nombre_garantia' :'', 'valor_garantia' : null, 'descripcion' : ''}
```

que son los campos que quiero llenar, sucede que a mi parecer los envío correctamente, porque me hace las validaciones bien en laravel, pero al momento de guardar este registro no sé como acceder a ellos. este es mi controlador y de momento solo valida.

```
public function store(StoreWarranty $request)
{

return ;
}
```

y los datos los envio de esta manera mediante axios.

```
 createWarranty(){
        var url = 'warranties';
        axios.post(url,{
            warranty : this.newWarranty
        }).then(response => {
            vm.getWarranty();
            vm.newWarranty = {'nombre_garantia' :'', 'valor_garantia' : null , 'descripcion' : ''};
            vm.errors = [];
            $('#create').modal('hide');
            $.notify('Nueva tarea creada con exito','success');
        }).catch(error => {
            vm.errors = error.response.data.errors
        })
    }
```

Comment: Te fijaste que lleguen correctamente utilizando el inspector de elementos y luego en la pestaña network?, sino capaz te falta el $fillable en el modelo Warranty.
U otro problema es que falta el _token via AJAX. Son todos problemas comunes cuando se envía vía ajax

Comment: ¿Cómo estás intentando guardar los datos? ¿Tienes creado en Laravel un modelo de tipo Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

Hola te recomiendo que en el return mandes como respuesta:

```
return response()->json([$reuqest->all()]);
```

y te fijes en el network que te esta mandando como respuesta el controlador.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por un lado si tiene salgun error en la peticion ahi veras claramente cual es el error y por otro veras con que estructura llegan tus datos.

En tu caso puedes acceder a tus datos con la siguiente linea de codigo.

```
$data = $request->input('newWarranty ');
```

$data se convierte en el objeto que tienes del lado del clientes por lo que para entrar a cada elemento del objeto debes de hacerlo de la siguiente manerja.

```
$data->newWarranty ->nombre_garantia  // te regresa nombre_garantia

$data->newWarranty ->valor_garantia// te regresa valor_garantia aun que sea nu

$data->newWarranty ->descripcion// te regresa descripcion
```

Si me llego a equivocar si hacer lo que te digo podras ver claramente si se trata de un objeto o de un arreglo.

para acceder a las propiedades de los objetos utilizas `"->"`

y para entrar a las propiedades de un array utilizas `"[]"`